# how to render a succes.html file if my contact is successfully added using the https req method for mailchimp API

Tags: node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

The latest Mailchimp API docs use the async function for batch subscription of members but i want to use the HTTPS req so that i will be able to tap into the status code so as to render the success.html and failure.html alternatively how can i access the status code if i am to use the async function of mailchimp API

I tried using the if-else statement after the async function (i.e if(response.status === 200){console.log(successful)}else{congsole.log(failed)}  but its not working so i want to opt in for the HTTPS req

Comment: Your question may attract answers if you provide a code samples and references to particular parts of Mailchimp API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used :

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
   const list_id ="*your audience id* "
   const url = "https://usXYY.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + list_id;
   const options = {
      method: "POST",
      auth: "anything:*yourAPIKEY*-usXYY",
      };

   const requestBody = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
        if(response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/success.html')
        }
        else{
            res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/failure.html')
        }
     })
  requestBody();
  }
 )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.